# How to mount FakeRAID to /home of a new system?

Tags: 10.10, raid

I'd like to know how to re-mount the FakeRAID disk to the new system safely so that I won't  losing my data.

I'm going to install ubunto10.10 to root

My old computer setting:

```
1 320G Disk for /
2 500G Disks for /home, using FakeRAID raid1
```

And my new computer setting:

```
1 new 500G Disk for /
2 500G Disks for /home, using FakeRAID raid1 (the same ones from the old computer)
```

When should I mount /home? before or after installing ubuntu?

Should I install RAID driver or the ubuntu 10.10 will support FakeRAID automatically?

This is my first time to recover a RAID system, so please please help me, thanks!!

Comment: Sorry for this question bouncing around so much. You should be able to find an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

During the install process, choose manual partitioning, and set the raid drive ( it will be named /dev/mapper/something ) to be mounted at /home, and do NOT check the format box.

Answer (score 0):

The safest approach is to completely avoid it (physically disconnect it if you can) during your install. Then you reduce the chance that you'll lose data along the way.